# How to add as much as possible edges to this graph that don't create a cycle?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Suppose you have a undirected graph. Do you know how to implement adding as much as possible edges to this graph that don't create a cycle?

If I go through all edges and skip ones that create a cycle, will it work?

Comment: Hint: look up the definition of a tree

Answer (score 1):

That should work because you will be running a slightly broken version of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm - one that doesn't sort the edges into ascending order of weight first.

Comment: How do you sort by weight edges that don't have weight (and don't even exist)?

Comment: I'm saying that you don't sort anything. But if you want to you could, for the purposes of this analogy, say that every edge has a weight of one, whether it exists or not.